# alignment of embedded search block

Tags: php, search, alignment

By embedding the search box(bar) into your template in drupal using

```
$block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view');
print render($block['content']);
```

Is there also a way to align it horizontally with the texts in the block?
because it always moves the search box down the texts of a block whenever I embed it.

sample target output upon embed

> hello world ( search box here)

output is always:

> hello world
>
> (Search box here)

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` will align blocks horizontally.

Add this property to the element which you want to be aligned horizontally.